# HTML table with different number of rows

Tags: html, html-table

I have a simple question :

we usually use

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> stuff1 </td>
        <td> stuff2 </td>
    <tr>
 ...
</table>
```

Therefore i can have on line with 3 columns and another with 4 columns. But I would like to do the contrary : on column with 3 rows and one column with 4 rows.

```
<table>
    <td>
        <tr> stuff1 </tr>
        <tr> stuff2 </tr>
    <td>
...
</table>
```

but swapping `<tr>` and `<td>` does not seem to works...

Comment: Can't you just leave one cell empty?

Comment: there is no point swapping td's and tr's, TD = Table division, TR= Table row

Comment: It is not that simple. What I want to do is to read a Json and diplay the information in columns.. but I don't know the size of each columns before reading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `rowspan` property. Here is a clue :

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">left</td>
    <td>T-right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B-Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is quite nice but in that case I still need to design the table line by line And I would love to be able to design it column by column

Comment: @Acryno
Then you may try using div components instead of table. More precisely you may try `col-xx-x` class in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `rowspan` attribute. It works exactly like `colspan`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to provide usage example in your answer, rather then linking to 3rd party page which may disappear, rendering your answer useless.

Comment: That is quite nice but in that case I still need to design the table line by line And I would love to be able to design it column by column